# How to return from completion handler inside a lazy set var

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-initialization, completionhandler

I want to fetch api to get content from server inside lazy var. Following is my code, I'm not sure how to get it working. Any clue? Im aware that we can't return from completion handler so I'm lost here. Not sure what other way to achieve this?

```
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        self.fetchPages()
    }()

func fetchPages() -> [UIViewController] {
    fetchIntroPages() { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
        } else {
            if result?.data != nil { 
                if (result?.success)! {
                    var newColoredViewControllerArray: [UIViewController] = []
                    for page in result!.data! {
                        newColoredViewControllerArray.append(self.newColoredViewController(pageId: page.id!, pageTitle: page.title!, pageContent: page.content!))
                    }
                    // This will not work
                    return newColoredViewControllerArray
                }
            } else { 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are forgetting that lazy var's are assigned closures in which you need to return the value of the property. Try adding `return` before calling `self.fetchPages()` in your lazy var.

Comment: Also are you sure want a lazy var? Maybe you just need an initially empty array and inside of fetchPages just say `self.orderedViewControllers = newColoredViewControllerArray`. But I don't know the full context on why you might need a lazy var.

Comment: I'm creating these view controllers via lazy var to be used in a page view controller. The content of pages in page view controller will be fetched from API as mentioned in above code.

Comment: @NSGangster the problem is in fetchPages() function as it will not return, xCode shows error. See this line: // This will not work
                    return newColoredViewControllerArray

Comment: the closure cannot contain asynchronous code, it just can't.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you're making async call, don’t return result, use completion handler instead

```
func fetchPages(_ completion: @escaping ([UIViewController]?) -> ()) {

    fetchIntroPages() { result, error in
        ...
            if let result = result { 
                if result.success {
                    ...
                    completion(newColoredViewControllerArray)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        completion(nil)
    }

}
```

then don't use `lazy` variable because you can’t provide return value since you’re making async call. If you need it, use just "normal" *stored* variable

```
var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController]?
```

Now where you need it, call `fetchPages` and in its completion closure assign your variable

```
fetchPages { viewControllers in
    if let viewControllers = viewControllers { // if you don't want to change controllers if there was any error
        self.orderedViewControllers = viewControllers
        ... // moment when you have `orderedViewControllers`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but this approach will require changing everything in the page controller as the current solution works only with lazy var. I can understand now that returning from completion handler is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare global array of [UIViewcontroller] and use semaphore while completion block

```
func fetchPages() -> [UIViewController] {
    var newColoredViewControllerArray = [UIViewController]()
    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    fetchIntroPages() { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
        } else {
            if result?.data != nil {
                if (result?.success)! {
                    for page in result!.data! {
                        newColoredViewControllerArray.append(self.newColoredViewController(pageId: page.id!, pageTitle: page.title!, pageContent: page.content!))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
   semaphore.wait()
   return newColoredViewControllerArray
}
```

OR
you can return viewcontroller array from using completion

```
func fetchPages(arrViewController:block) {
    var newColoredViewControllerArray = [UIViewController]()
    fetchIntroPages() { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
        } else {
            if result?.data != nil {
                if (result?.success)! {
                    for page in result!.data! {
                        newColoredViewControllerArray.append(self.newColoredViewController(pageId: page.id!, pageTitle: page.title!, pageContent: page.content!))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        arrViewController(newColoredViewControllerArray)

    }
}
```

I hope this is helpfull for you

Comment: a very very bad idea since you are essentially blocking the main thread.